# Why angular-cli do not generate a shared folder when creating a component?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli, it suppose to create a component with a sub folder called shared with index.ts, but I am not seeing that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was taken out with the addition of `NgModule` as of rc5. The need to nest components inside of shared directories is against the pattern of declaring them within a given module.